# How to use mutate_at() in R to change columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to replace all the instances of `""` in the columns: `VEHICLE.TYPE.CODE` and `CONTRIBUTING.FACTOR.VEHICLE`.

My code is:

```
df %>% 
  select(VEHICLE.TYPE.CODE.1, VEHICLE.TYPE.CODE.2, 
         VEHICLE.TYPE.CODE.3, VEHICLE.TYPE.CODE.4, VEHICLE.TYPE.CODE.5, 
         CONTRIBUTING.FACTOR.VEHICLE.1, CONTRIBUTING.FACTOR.VEHICLE.2, 
         CONTRIBUTING.FACTOR.VEHICLE.3, CONTRIBUTING.FACTOR.VEHICLE.4, 
         CONTRIBUTING.FACTOR.VEHICLE.5) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(contains(" ")), funs("NONE"))
```

However, this doesn't work. The `""` are not replaced by `"NONE"`. Why does my code not work, and how can I fix my code to get `"NONE"` in my columns?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `matches` to match column names with a pattern and use `replace` to change values.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate_at(vars(matches('VEHICLE.TYPE.CODE|CONTRIBUTING.FACTOR.VEHICLE')), 
                     ~replace(., . == "", "NONE"))
```

Note that `mutate_at` is going to be replaced by `across` in future release of `dplyr` in which case syntax would change to :

```
df %>%
    mutate(across(matches('VEHICLE.TYPE.CODE|CONTRIBUTING.FACTOR.VEHICLE')),
           ~replace(., . == "", "NONE"))
```